# svn: E160005: Invalid control character '0x10' in path

Tags: xcode, svn

On: `svn import project_path server_path -m 'import first'`

I got the following error:

> svn: E160005: Invalid control character '0x10' in path

Comment: 0x10 is the newline character

Comment: i rename that file TestViewController.h to TestVC.h but still not solved ...

Comment: Just clarification: 0x10 is not new line, this is DLE (Data Line Escape)

Comment: Oops - I forgot about the hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this error.

SVN gives the which file contains the error. 
In my case the file name looks like **TestViewController.h in Xcode and Finder** but while you see **in terminal it shows TestViewController?.h**

see how it looks in terminal
[image]

so i rename the file with command **mv TestViewController?.h to TestViewController.h** and my error solved.

Answer (score 0):

Verify names of all files and directories in your project.

There is a character in the path that is must never be in Subversion repository, therefore the client displays the error. Moreover, normally such character should not be used in file and directory names ever. The same is true for newline character (0x0A) and some others.